# CSS tabs position left in IE but in Mozilla they are centered. Is there a fix for IE?

Tags: html, css

The tabs work perfectly.  I am just having a problem with the placement in IE.  In Mozilla it shows the placement of the tabs perfectly but when I load the page in IE it moves the tab to the complete left of the table the tabs are in.

Here is my CSS code:

```
 a:active {
outline: none;
 }
 a:focus {
-moz-outline-style: none;
 }
 #tabs_container {
width: 626px;
font-family: Arial;
font-size: 10px;
}
 #tabs_container ul.tabs {
list-style: none;
border-bottom: none;
height: 25px; 
margin: 0px;

  }
  #tabs_container ul.tabs li {
 float: left;
   }
  #tabs_container ul.tabs li a {
padding: 6px 9px;
display: block;
border-left: 1px solid #90afcb;
border-top: 1px solid #90afcb;
border-right: 1px solid #90afcb;
border-bottom: 1px solid #90afcb;
margin-right: 4px;
text-decoration: none;
background-color: #ffffff;
    }
    #tabs_container ul.tabs li.active a {
background-color: #90afcb;
padding-top: 6px;
    }
   div.tab_contents_container {
border: none;
border-top: none;
padding: 10px;
font-size: 10px;
    }
    div.tab_contents {
display: none;
    }
    div.tab_contents_active {
display: block;
    }
    div.clear {
clear: both;
    }
```

HTML

```
  <!-- These are the tabs -->
  <ul class="tabs">
    <li class="active">
      <a href="#" rel="#tab_1_contents" class="tab"><span>Dienstleistung | Services</span></a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#" rel="#tab_2_contents" class="tab"><span>Über uns | About us</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#" rel="#tab_3_contents" class="tab"><span>Netzwerken | Networking</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#" rel="#tab_4_contents" class="tab"><span>Social Media</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#" rel="#tab_5_contents" class="tab"><span>Impressum</span></a></li>
  </ul>
```

I would be very grateful for any assistance you could provide.
Many thanks

Comment: hi i made fiddle in your code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jhunlio/wLM8U/1/) is there any image so that i know what you want to achieve

Comment: I have added the javascript.  It will not work for me.  I have uploaded my page at larue-consulting.de  It works fine except in IE.  IE throws the tabs totally to the left.  I have tried everything to get them to center, but when I play with the position it screws it up in Mozilla.  I am wondering which is the less of two evils.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hi did you try to add `float` `#tabs_container ul.tabs` and `#tabs_container ul.tabs li a`

```
#tabs_container ul.tabs {
     float:left;
    border:1px solid red;
list-style: none;
border-bottom: none;
height: 25px; 
margin: 0px;

  }

  #tabs_container ul.tabs li a {
float:left;
padding: 6px 9px;
display: block;
border-left: 1px solid #90afcb;
border-top: 1px solid #90afcb;
border-right: 1px solid #90afcb;
border-bottom: 1px solid #90afcb;
margin-right: 4px;
text-decoration: none;
background-color: #ffffff;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.  When I change the ul.tabs with the float it pushes all of the tabs to the left.  It pushes them to a super extreme.  I have sent you a message over your site.  Would you be willing to take over?